# Difference in Sharing modes of PriceBook (Product Portfolio)

Tags: sharing, pricebook

When I look at any Product Portfolio sharing page I found these option:

> 1) To add a Public Group in which we can share the particular PP with Group's, Roles, Roles and Subordinate & User's. 
>     2) To add Roles, Roles and Subordinate & User's in the Sharing page of PP.

Can you tell me difference between these two like: 
a. If I am adding *Public Group* to it and in that PublicGroup I am given some **ABC - Roles and Subordinate** access. 
AND 
b. If I'll give the same access of **ABC - Roles and Subordinate** in the sharing page of PP itself

> What is the difference between these two types of Sharing and How it is different ?

Also in Salesforce help it is mentioned to give Sharing Permission to PP with Public Group as default recommended. 

"PP as Product Portfolio or PriceBook."
Thanks,
Chirag